# why all date strings are changed into numbers?

Tags: r

```
start=as.Date("2013-09-02")
x[1:140]<-start
for(i in 2:140){
  x[i]<-x[i-1]+1 }
```

what i get is something as such:

```
[1] "2013-09-02" "2013-09-03" "2013-09-04" "2013-09-05" "2013-09-06"
```

when i run :

```
y<-matrix(x,nrow=20,byrow=TRUE) 
> y

   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
 [1,] 15950 15951 15952 15953 15954 15955 15956
```

all the string are changed into numbers,why?how can i not to change them in y?

Comment: you can avoid the `for` loop to create the vector of dates, just use the vectorized `+` and `:` functions as in `start + (0:140)` ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is R doesn't allow matrices to be populated with dates.  Both `"matrix"` and `"Date"` are classes.  The underlying representation of a Date object in R is just an integer.  So when you create your matrix `y`, it takes the underlying data from `x` (which is an array of integers), adds a dimension attribute, and makes the class `"matrix"`.

There's not any clean way around this problem.  There are a few hacks you can use, though.  For example, you could explicitly force `y` to be of class `"Date"` as well as `"matrix"` with `class(y)<-c("matrix","Date")`.  `y` would still print out as just a vector of dates, but you would be able to manipulate it using matrix cordinates:

```
> class(y)<-c("matrix","Date")
> head(y)
 [1] "2013-09-02" "2013-09-09" "2013-09-16" "2013-09-23" "2013-09-30"
 [6] "2013-10-07" "2013-09-03" "2013-09-10" "2013-09-17" "2013-09-24"
[11] "2013-10-01" "2013-10-08" "2013-09-04" "2013-09-11" "2013-09-18"
[16] "2013-09-25" "2013-10-02" "2013-10-09" "2013-09-05" "2013-09-12"
[21] "2013-09-19" "2013-09-26" "2013-10-03" "2013-10-10" "2013-09-06"
[26] "2013-09-13" "2013-09-20" "2013-09-27" "2013-10-04" "2013-10-11"
[31] "2013-09-07" "2013-09-14" "2013-09-21" "2013-09-28" "2013-10-05"
[36] "2013-10-12" "2013-09-08" "2013-09-15" "2013-09-22" "2013-09-29"
[41] "2013-10-06" "2013-10-13"
> y[1,]
[1] "2013-09-02" "2013-09-03" "2013-09-04" "2013-09-05" "2013-09-06"
[6] "2013-09-07" "2013-09-08"
> y[1,]<-y[1,]+1
> y[1,]
[1] "2013-09-03" "2013-09-04" "2013-09-05" "2013-09-06" "2013-09-07"
[6] "2013-09-08" "2013-09-09"
```

You could also use a data frame instead of a matrix:

```
> y<-data.frame(y)
> y<-data.frame(lapply(y,function(x) {class(x)<-"Date";x}))
> head(y)
          X1         X2         X3         X4         X5         X6         X7
1 2013-09-02 2013-09-03 2013-09-04 2013-09-05 2013-09-06 2013-09-07 2013-09-08
2 2013-09-09 2013-09-10 2013-09-11 2013-09-12 2013-09-13 2013-09-14 2013-09-15
3 2013-09-16 2013-09-17 2013-09-18 2013-09-19 2013-09-20 2013-09-21 2013-09-22
4 2013-09-23 2013-09-24 2013-09-25 2013-09-26 2013-09-27 2013-09-28 2013-09-29
5 2013-09-30 2013-10-01 2013-10-02 2013-10-03 2013-10-04 2013-10-05 2013-10-06
6 2013-10-07 2013-10-08 2013-10-09 2013-10-10 2013-10-11 2013-10-12 2013-10-13
```

A third possiblity is to keep the elements in `y` in character format, and then convert them to dates using `as.Date` when you need them:

```
> y<-matrix(as.character(x),nrow=20,byrow=T)
> head(y)
     [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]        
[1,] "2013-09-02" "2013-09-03" "2013-09-04" "2013-09-05" "2013-09-06"
[2,] "2013-09-09" "2013-09-10" "2013-09-11" "2013-09-12" "2013-09-13"
[3,] "2013-09-16" "2013-09-17" "2013-09-18" "2013-09-19" "2013-09-20"
[4,] "2013-09-23" "2013-09-24" "2013-09-25" "2013-09-26" "2013-09-27"
[5,] "2013-09-30" "2013-10-01" "2013-10-02" "2013-10-03" "2013-10-04"
[6,] "2013-10-07" "2013-10-08" "2013-10-09" "2013-10-10" "2013-10-11"
     [,6]         [,7]        
[1,] "2013-09-07" "2013-09-08"
[2,] "2013-09-14" "2013-09-15"
[3,] "2013-09-21" "2013-09-22"
[4,] "2013-09-28" "2013-09-29"
[5,] "2013-10-05" "2013-10-06"
[6,] "2013-10-12" "2013-10-13"
> as.Date(y[1,])
[1] "2013-09-02" "2013-09-03" "2013-09-04" "2013-09-05" "2013-09-06"
[6] "2013-09-07" "2013-09-08"
```

Comment: +1 for the workarounds.   Keep in mind though `"The underlying representation of a Date object in R is just an integer"` applies to factors as well, which are allowed in matrices

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Interesting, I wasn't aware that factors were allowed in matrices without a hack.  How do you construct such a matrix?  If I execute `x<-sample(c("a","b","c"),50,T); x<-as.factor(x); y<-matrix(x,10,5)` then `mode(y)` returns `"character"`.  If I then call `y<-as.factor(y)`, then `y` stops being a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

That's just a weird behaviour of `matrix`.  Dates are internally stored as an integer of the number of days since 1st Jan 1970.  Those are the numbers that you are seeing.

Probably the best option is to store them in a data frame instead.

FYI, you can create a sequence of dates using `seq`.

```
x <- seq(as.Date("2013-09-02"), length.out = 140, by = "1 day")
```

Comment: Perhaps explain that it is how `matrix` converts everything to a common type, and in the case of dates, I believe it would use `as.vector` which would remove the date attributes.